# How to transfer cookies to the page that I would like to download html?

Tags: python, cookies, request, urllib

Executes the code:

```
response = requests.get("https://google.com")
print(response.cookies)
cookies_dict = {"my_cookie": "cookie_value"}
response = requests.get("https://google.com", cookies=cookies_dict)
print(response.cookies)
```

I get a reply:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

I use libraries:

```
from urllib.request import Request
```

I would like to transfer the cookie data to the website so that it can download the HTML content from the website with the use of this cookie.
Unfortunately, when you try to send cookies, they are not added. I have already tried many ways. Unsuccessfully.

Could someone help me how to send cookies? How to otherwise download the html content of a page with assigned cookies?

The website I use in the project uses cookies for authorization. Without sending the cookie, I will not be able to download the content of the website.

//edit
I changed the page example because it did not work like my project needed page.

Answer (score 0):

If you print response.text, you can see the cookies

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
print(response.text)
cookies_dict = {"my_cookie": "cookie_value"}
response = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies", cookies=cookies_dict)
print(response.text)
```

Output

```
{
  "cookies": {}
}

{
  "cookies": {
    "my_cookie": "cookie_value"
  }
}
```

Or you can access the cookies directly by using `response.json()['cookies']`

Comment: I gave a bad page example :)
For example, I would like to upload a cookie to the website "https://google.com" and download its content.
When I check response.cookies, the added cookie does not appear.